# Check if image copied from Google

Tags: php, jquery, json, image, google-image-search

I'm working on a SEO (search engine optimization) project, which is build with PHP and Jquery/Json.

For this project I want to create a function to check if a image is copied from a search engine like Google. I've checked checked the Google image search API, but I can't find some useful information, so I hope someone here can help me.

Comment: Why? And what do you mean by copied from Google? Are we talking image URLs? Saved and uploaded files? The request doesn't make sense.

Comment: if the image is saved from google to the local server, there won't be anyway to check if it is from google.  Also google's images usually just reference another site's image so it isn't "from" google.  How does this affect seo ranking

Comment: I wan't to check if there are used images from a search engine as Google because a image of Google has copyrights.

Answer (score 0):

Google don't offer any API services to do that except the icon on the right of the search input : [image: https://i.gyazo.com/8dc43add1e96eb1cbd122fd7f65122cb.png]

You can use this service non free : https://services.tineye.com/MatchEngine

Comment: That link doesn't seem quite right: for a whole-internet search the relevant API is their [TinEye API](https://services.tineye.com/TinEyeAPI).